# NSViewController displayed inside a containerView doesn't align itself to the bounds of the Container in Cocoa App Swift [Mac OS ]

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

The code of the NSViewcontroller with container view

```
@IBOutlet weak var cv: NSView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
      let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "vc2") as! VC2
    addChild(vc2)
    vc2.view.frame=cv.bounds
    cv.addSubview(vc2.view)
    cv.wantsLayer=true
    cv.layer?.backgroundColor=NSColor.red.cgColor

}
```

The code of the NSViewController to be displayed in the container view

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.wantsLayer=true
    self.view.layer?.backgroundColor=NSColor.white.cgColor

}
```

I have added the white layer to describe my question better
[image]

I have set the constraints for container view properly in the storyboard and have checked that as well the container view occupies the whole ViewController.

Why is my viewController set to only a portion of the container view and not fully?

ContainerView Bounds Console image
[image]

Initial size of your cv and complete window is 480*270. And at that point, your vc2 size is also correct. But then I resize your complete window. The cv resizes but not the vc2.

Comment: What are container view bounds? Possible to color the container view with some red color to visualize better?

Comment: try with viewdidappear once

Comment: @kerry Changed to red for better understanding , pls check now

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik why viewdidappear bro it appears properly

Comment: this needs a little bit of debugging. Can you print the bounds of cv in viewDidLoad (first snippet) and see if this is the correct size?

Comment: @kerry added the image. check it out

Comment: is your complete window size only 480*270?

Comment: @kerry no but I have set the window size to 480*270 on storyboard but when I maximise the window the container view properly resizes as shown in red colour but why does my vc2 not resize

Comment: Ok, so this is what I understand from your comment. Initial size of your cv and complete window is 480*270. And at that point, your vc2 size is also correct. But then you resize your complete window. Your cv resizes but not your vc2. Is that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193236/discussion-between-prithvi-venu-and-kerry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you are using constraints, they resize with changes in layout. But in vc2, you have given it a constant size at the start. Which is why even if you resize the window, it does not get resized. Try programmatically assigning constraints to vc2.view to attach it to its superview (cv). This will make sure that vc2.view will resize with cv.

Make sure to assign constraints after `cv.addSubview(vc2.view)`.

Check out [this library](https://github.com/roberthein/TinyConstraints) which will remove a lot of boiler plate code while creating constraints.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your container view resize when you resize your NSViewController(MainViewController) then just add container view to your main NSViewcontroller as shown in screenshot

[image]

Provide following AutoLayout constraints to your container view :
**Leading , tralling ,Top , Bottom** constraint to super view

[image]

And Last connect your vc2 to container view that's it.

[image]

Now, Your container view resize automatically when you resize your MainViewcontroller. No need to write code for container view in MainViewController.

Comment: I need to embed the view controller in the container view programatically not using storyboards.